# How do I properly set DPI when saving a pillow image?

Tags: python, image, dpi, python-imaging-library

I am trying to create images programatically on Python using [Pillow library](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow) but I'm having problems with the image quality of the text inside the image.

I want to save the Image the I generate to PNG, so I'm setting the DPI when saving according to [this](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/handbook/image-file-formats.html#png), but whether I save with *dpi=(72,72)* or *dpi=(600,600)* it visually looks the same.

My code for doing it is the following:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

def generate_empty_canvas(width, height, color='white'):
    size = (width, height)
    return Image.new('RGB', size, color=color)

def draw_text(text, canvas):
    font = ImageFont.truetype('Verdana.ttf', 10)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(canvas)
    if '\n' not in text:
        draw.text((0, 0), text, font=font, fill='black')
    else:
        draw.multiline_text((0, 0), text, font=font, fill='black')

def create_sample():
    text = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\nbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\nccccccccccccccccccccc'
    canvas = generate_empty_canvas(200, 50)
    draw_text(text, canvas)
    canvas.save('low_quality.png', dpi=(72, 72))
    canvas.save('high_quality.png', dpi=(600, 600))
```

The low_quality.png is:

[image: Image dpi=72]

The high_quality.png is:

[image: Image dpi=600]

As it's visible by the images the quality didn't change.
What am I doing wrong here?

**Where do I set the DPI so that the image really has dpi=600?**

Comment: Just so you don't fall into this trap, when trying to set DPI using Pillow, use a newer version if possible. I was having problems with 6.0.0 not saving DPI correctly. I'm using 8.2.0 and it is definitely working. Sort of unrelated to you actual question, but some folks might find it useful.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The DPI values are only metadata on computer images. They give hints on how to display or print an image.

Printing a 360×360 image with 360 dpi will result in a 1×1 inches printout.

A simplified way to explain it: The DPI setting recommends a zoom level for the image.

Saving with other DPIs will not change the content of the image. If you want a larger image create a larger canvas and use a larger font.