# How do I save my files at 300 dpi using Pillow(PIL)?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I opening an image file using the pillow(PIL) library and saving it again under a different name.  But when I save the image under the different name  it takes my original 300 DPI file and makes it a 72 DPI file.  I tried adding dpi=(300, 300) But still no success.

**See code**

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open('image-1.jpg')
image.save('image-2.jpg' , dpi=(300, 300))
```

**My original file(image-1.jpg)**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/x7xj6hyoemv3t94/image_info_1.jpg?raw=1

**My copied file(image-2.jpg)**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dpcnkfozefobopn/image_info_2.jpg?raw=1

Notice how they still have the same image size: 8.45.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly set DPI when saving a pillow image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31351384/how-do-i-properly-set-dpi-when-saving-a-pillow-image) Bottom line: Your image is still the same, hence the same file size. DPI is just meta data, especially for printing. Also: Couldn't reproduce stated behaviour. I get a 300 dpi JPG image, when using your code.

Comment: Are you on a mac or pc?  Im on mac os catalina adobe photoshop cc 20.08

Comment: Windows workstation, and Windows in-built data information as well as ImageJ state 300 dpi when inspecting the generated JPG image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @HansHirse explaining that the meta data was missing AKA exif information I saved the image with the exif info and it worked

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open('image-1.jpg')
exif = image.info['exif']
image.save('image-2.jpg' , exif=exif)
```

Comment: Well done, thank you for sharing back with the community. You can accept your own answer and bag the points.