Increase DPI for high quality images of Folium maps
Folium allows for screenshot of it's map using Selenium.
link
However, there is no option to take a high quality screenshot with increased DPI. Any way around this?
img_data = map._to_png()
img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(img_data))
img.save(f'image_pci_{fix_pci}.png')

assuming map is your folium map.

I never used this, but img.save can have parameter for DPI, but read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31351384/how-do-i-properly-set-dpi-when-saving-a-pillow-image . Also, may you want to change image zoom when you take screenshot from selenium driver, or change selenium driver resolution

looks like they use Selenium to take a screenshot of the page.  That'll be stuck at your machine's DPI... usually that's 72 or 96.
